# Decompilation of (binary,NDK) C apps vs. Java apps (Dalvik bytecode)

Tags: android, android-ndk, decompiling

Well,

since I'm interested in reengineering I spend a lot of time on Android reengineering so far.

Nevertheless I got to a point, where I had the problem of compiled, binary C-Code (NDK) and I got to know that it's very difficult to decompile it back to C/C++ than decompiling a DEX-file back to more or less well Java sources.

What's the reason for this? I mean the bytecode is executed by the Dalvik VM and in case of a usual binary file it's executed by the real processor directly instead. Both are pretty similar except for some additional emulation layers, isn't it? I don't see that much differences at the moment or the reason for this problem.

Do you have any information for me why it's more difficult to decompile a usual binary file (e.g. ELF or MS EXE) back to the C source?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is that the C/C++ code does not contain any reflective information in it and C/C++ has inline functions, macros, and unrolled loops that the Java compiler just doesn't do (as much as C/C++ compilers do).  It is also possible to optimize C/C++ so extensively that all you can do is decompile to assembly because there are no references to the applications own functions. (References to the system's functions will be found though.)

Answer (score 2):

BTW, Hex-Rays ARM Decompiler makes reverse-engineering job much easier, check this out: http://www.hex-rays.com/hexarm_compare0.shtml

The other question is that it costs much...