# How can I avoid the decompile APK to Java file in my app

Tags: java, android, encryption, apk, decompiling

Anyone can help me to Avoid the decompile my app APK to Java file ?

i would like to encrypt my code in file APK and avoid some tool to reverse the file .apk to Java file

Thanks so much!

***Sorry: thank with Proguard.cfg
However: with tool: dex2jar . I can also decompile APK***

Comment: Sure. You can definitely decompile the APK. I see that you unaccepted my answer. What more would you like to know? It is not theoretically possible to hide the code if you also want the same user to be able to run it. Obfuscation is the way to make it harder.

Answer (score 5):

Encryption will be hard, but you can obfuscate the byte code to make it harder to read. Check out [Proguard](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html).

You cannot make it impossible to decompile if you also want it possible to run. This would be true even if your program was made in for example C or C++ (just harder).

You could perhaps load parts of the program dynamically and encrypt those parts, but then the user would need to specify an encryption key and will therefore be able to decompile anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to obfuscate your code, using [ProGuard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/) for instance. You can read the [following](http://www.androidengineer.com/2010/07/optimizing-obfuscating-and-shrinking.html) article which describes the process for an Android application.

Comment: Thanks Amokrane, after using ProGuard
I can also decompile the apk by using tool: dex2jar. :(.
Even the project code source in your link. i can also decompile.
Do you explain more detail plase ?

Comment: He never said that you wouldn't be able to decompile it. ProGuard just obfuscates it, which means that the code you get after decompilation will be harder to read. Preventing decompilation from an APK is not possible since you must be able to run the code (and thus read the instructions).

Answer (score 1):

Use NDK for the most critical code

- http://cerezo.name/blog/2011/03/23/android-decompilation-obfuscation/
- [Decompilation of (binary,NDK) C apps vs. Java apps (Dalvik bytecode)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263576/decompilation-of-binary-ndk-c-apps-vs-java-apps-dalvik-bytecode)