# Stop Astro Manager to Take Backup

Tags: android, deployment

People who download the applications from the play store can easily take the APK files for the application using **Astro Manager, and other related apps**. These apk's are further **decompiled to get all the Resources files and codes** of the corresponding applications by following a series of steps.

My Question is : How to stop my application by being backed up with Astro Manager. ( **I dont want that anyone should take a backup of it**)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible actully that filemanager is not taking a backup of apk.

Android System is take the backup of apk when the app is downloaded and we are able to copy that apk in other folder in sdcard by following some steps but we are not able to delete that apk from the android system as it is prevented by the system.

To restricate the decompiling of apk you have to use **ProGaurd** see this [Prevent Decompiling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9363236/how-can-i-avoid-the-decompile-apk-to-java-file-in-my-app) and also other method are availbale but that are also not 100% perfact.

And apk which is Shared via bluetooth by using  [**MyAPPSharer**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.yschi.MyAppSharer&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDEsImNvbS55c2NoaS5NeUFwcFNoYXJlciJd) type app to avoid that application to  work in device than you have to use [Application Licensing](http://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/index.html) that will check that app is downloaded from playstore or not if not than it will show a dialog as with message pasted by us that you are using illegel version of application etc...

Answer (score 1):

By using Link2SD or other app, you can converse the app in system app. At this stage will not be visible anymore for Astro file manager.

Also, I have tried this:
 1. I have installed and run the apk file on SD card; 
 2. I have installed an encryption app on the SD card (Encryption
    Manager); 3. I have encrypted app libraries on SD card (apk file
    itself can not be encrypted, otherwise the app will not launch and
    run). Launching the app still works, no probs whatsoever. By
    deleting the encryption app (Encryption Manager) from SD card, the
    encrypted libraries remains still encrypted, and I can still launch
    the apk file. Apk file is still visible for Astro file manager, but
    can not be backed up/cpoied. When trying this, a message occur: App
    protected, will skip back up.